# Array of unknown number of elements in c

Tags: c, arrays, variables, size

i'm trying to make a game in C, and my problem is this:
I need to have some kind of method in C, that does basicaly what this python code does:

```
array = list();
len(array)       #returns 0
x = 1
array.append(x)
len(array)       #returns 1
array.append(2)
len(array)       #returns 2
```

This is just the basic method that I need to do, the test if it's less than 5 is just to be different sizes array, originally my problem is how to manipulate the gunshots in my game, creating them pressing space on the keyboard(appending the gunshot to an until now empty array), and then i have to do something like this, just in C:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    print array[i]
```

originally, that's when the loop is running and I have to determine if the gunshot is visible and move it or not, I don't know how to determine the lenght of the array in C, specially if the array has a variable size(can increase size in time)
In Python it would be easy to handle this, but I don't know how to do it in C, and since my game has to be in C 'cause it's for a college class..

Comment: C does not have built-in support for variable-size arrays.

Comment: Also, you should show what C code you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a linked list. Search 'dynamic memory allocation' on Google - then use it to create a linked list.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a linked list instead of an array, because you'll eventually want to remove arbitrary elements.  (Bullet 1 is still travelling across the screen, but bullet 3 hit a wall and bullet 6 hit an enemy.)  You can do that directly in your bullet struct rather than as a separate data structure:

```
typedef struct bullet_t {
  /* ...game logic... */
  struct bullet_t* next;
} bullet;
```

Comment: that's exactly what I need, sorry, I'm kind of a noob in C..could you please explain a little more how to do it, like an example for the struct and the mannipulation to create and destroy the bullet, or just a documentation that I could use to learn it, I would really apprechiate it

Answer (score 1):

C does not support variable sized arrays; if C++ is an option, go for `std::vector`. If not, you will have to implement that in C on your own. I would personally suggest doing something close to what `std::vector` does - each time you run out of memory, `realloc` twice as much.

Comment: You could compile your code as c++ while still using c syntax, and use stl::vector. The old adage of treating c++ as c on steroids!

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do what you want to do, but I advice chained list.
Basically, the issue for converting your python code into C-code is the fact that you have to manually allocate your variables most of the time, and here you have. So you can do a chained list, where you allocate every new element with a malloc, and then you link it to the rest of the list with a pointer.

Then, to know the size, just follow the list with a counter.

Good luck. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a different [ADT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type). For example a linked list, or a [Set ADTs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29) (if you google a bit, you'll probably find finished ones). However, if you absolutely need to use arrays, then you should look up dynamically allocated ones. Here is an implementation example. (Not tested)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int *array;
    int size;
    int capacity;
} array_t;

#define ARRAY_INIT_CAPACITY 4

array_t *new_array(){
    array_t *arr=malloc(sizeof(array_t));
    arr->array=malloc(sizeof(int)*ARRAY_INIT_CAPACITY);
    arr->size=0;
    arr->capacity=ARRAY_INIT_CAPACITY;
    return arr;
}

void increase_array(array_t *array){
    int new_capacity=array->capacity*2;
    int *new_location = realloc(array->array, new_capacity*sizeof(int));
    if (!new_location) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    array->capacity=new_capacity;
    array->array=new_location;
}

void array_append(array_t *array, int item){
    if (array->size >= array->capacity){
        increase_array(array);
    }
    array->array[array->size]=item;
    array->size+=1;
}
int array_size(array_t *array){
    return array->size;
}
array_t *myArray=new_array();
```

I'd recommend learning about [dynamic memory allocation](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation) and [Arrays in C](http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_arrays.html).
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Basically OOP in C ;)

Comment: That's basically what I needed, thanks, I use array 'cause it's the ADT that I know that I could do it, I see some things about chained or linked lists, and I don't know how to do it or what it is

Comment: You could check [this](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists) out :) (And please accept the answer if it satisfied your needs!)